# Javascript offsetHeight not updating from initial rendered height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm loading content into a div using the infinite scroll method but it's not working as it should be.

This is the calculation I'm using in my `window.onscroll` function to load new content :

```
window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

But `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` never receives an updated value when new content is added. It always stays at the initial value, which is causing the entire infinite scroll to work in reverse, only loading new content when you scroll to the top of the screen and not the bottom as expected.

I've made sure that the appended divs are being put in the right element, also tried using `document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetHeight` instead of pulling it off the body but I'm getting the same result.

I've also tried removing all relevant css styling just in case that was causing the issue, again, same result.

I know it's impossible for anybody to diagnose this in any detail without a lot more information, but it's a big project with many other elements that could potentially be causing this issue, so I'm just asking if anybody else has ever run up against something similar or has any suggestions of other things to try?

Many thanks!

** Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m3o0ro4jqp) of a working version (where I got the code from originally). I just don't know why the offsetHeight element doesn't update in my codebase.

**EDIT** Added my React Component below, not sure that it will help diagnosis though.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ProfileFollowers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: false,
      hasMore: true,
      isLoading: false,
      followers: []
    };
    
    window.onscroll = () => {
      const {
        loadFollowers,
        state: { error, isLoading, hasMore }
      } = this;

      if (error || isLoading || !hasMore) return;

      if (
        window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight
      ) {
        loadFollowers();
      }
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadFollowers();
  }

  loadFollowers = () => {
    
      axios
        .get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
        .then(results => {
          
          const nextFollowers = results.data.results.map(follower => ({
            email: follower.email,
            name: Object.values(follower.name).join(' '),
            photo: follower.picture.medium,
            username: follower.login.username,
            uuid: follower.login.uuid
          }));

          this.setState({
            hasMore: this.state.followers.length < 100,
            isLoading: false,
            followers: [...this.state.followers, ...nextFollowers]
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.setState({
            error: err.message,
            isLoading: false
          });
        });
  };

  render() {
    const { error, hasMore, isLoading, followers } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="profile-followers-wrap">
        {followers.map(follower => (
          <Fragment key={follower.username}>
            <hr />
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <img
                alt={follower.username}
                src={follower.photo}
                style={{
                  borderRadius: '50%',
                  height: 72,
                  marginRight: 20,
                  width: 72
                }}
              />
              <div>
                <h2 style={{ marginTop: 0 }}>@{follower.username}</h2>
                <p>Name: {follower.name}</p>
                <p>Email: {follower.email}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
        <hr />
        {error && <div style={{ color: '#900' }}>{error}</div>}
        {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
        {!hasMore && <div>No more!</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ProfileFollowers.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProfileFollowers);
```

**EDIT 2** Added screenshot of console to show the problem in action.

[image]

Comment: try to re create the problem in https://codesandbox.io/ so that way people would be able to help you debugging it.

Comment: @FabioAntunes It's not that simple. It's a pretty big React project. I've just added a sandbox of a working version. This is a single page app. Mine has other elements like a sidebar and header and the content is loaded into content.

Comment: I've no doubt the problem is in my code somewhere, more than likely to do with the layout. But i've tried everything I could think of to try and find it and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @spice Where and how in your code are you listening to scroll events?

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac I'll add my component, I'm not sure it will help though. Hold tight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FFS! Found it... I had the height set to 100% on the global html element :

```
html {
  height: 100%; // Arrrrggghhhh!
  width: 100%;
}
```

This was preventing the `offsetHeight` from updating.

You won't believe how long it took to debug this so I'm leaving this here in case anybody else ever stumbles across a similar issue. Hope I can save somebody else a few hours of hair pulling :)

Comment: Glad you found it. Sorry I wasn't able to help more.

Comment: Thank you for leaving this here. It's 2023 and I just ran into this issue.